# Use index to set value on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, indexing

Could someone please tell me how I can use the index in this situation?

I have a text field, which is my multiplication factor

```
<input type="text" id="value">
```

And I have a table that has 2 fields arranged in the same tr

One with a fixed value
And one that must be the result of multiplying these two values.

Example:
In input I set value = 2

Field Value2 = Value 1 * 2

| Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 8 |

My jQuery function looks like this:

```
 $( "#btn" ).on( "click", function() 
     {
        let vlUS    = $('#value').val()
        
        $("table > tbody  > tr > td > input")
            .each(function (index) {
            
            let vl1   = $('.val1').val()
            let vl2   =  vl1 * vlUS 

            $('.val2').val(vl2)
           
        });
     });
```

Using this way, assigns the same value to all "value2" fields

How can I use index to tune the process?

Comment: Can you post table codes  also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over the rows and use each row instance to `find()` the specific inputs within that row

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  let vlUS = $('#value').val();

  $("table > tbody  > tr").each(function(index) {
    const $row = $(this);
    
    let vl1 = $row.find('.val1').val()
    let vl2 = vl1 * vlUS

    $row.find('.val2').val(vl2);

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">
  Calculate
</button> US: <input id="value" value="5" />

<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="val1" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="val2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="val1" value="6"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="val2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it worked correctly

Thank you so much for your time and have a great day

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  $("table tbody tr").each(function(index, elem) {
    $(".val2", elem).val(parseInt($(".val1", elem).val()) * parseInt($("#value").val()));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Calculate</button> US: <input id="value" value="5" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="val1" value="3"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="val2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="val1" value="6"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="val2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Simply reduces the operation to one line. Also ensures that if the User enters a Letter; it won't fail.